# Why is my FormData object POSTing into a django dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, django, form-data

When I submit a form via an ajax `FormData` object to my Django back-end, my `request.POST` seems to be a dictionary whose values are lists, not strings. I.e., I expect this:

```
In [1]: request.POST
Out[1]: {'somekey': 'somevalue', ...}
```

Instead, I'm getting this:

```
In [2]: request.POST
Out[2]: {'somekey': ['somevalue'], ...}
```

Here's how I submit:

```
var form = document.forms["my-form"]
//note, all of #my-form's inputs are type="hidden" if it makes a difference...
var fd = new FormData(form);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/my-view/', true);
xhr.onload = function(){
    if(xhr.status == 200){
       //doStuff();...
    }
}
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
xhr.send(fd);
```

Obviously, I could loop through my request.POST dictionary and turn those lists into strings before trying to instantiate a django `Form` object with the data (for validation purposes), but I get a feeling that something is wrong. Why is my `FormData` object turning into a dictionary of lists (which obviously can't be used as-is to create a valid django `Form`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) like `request.POST` can handle multiple items for each key. This is the case whether it's an ajax request or not.

Don't worry about it, you don't have to preprocess the data. If you instantiate your form with `request.POST`, the form will handle it fine.

If you are manually handling post data, note that there is a `getlist` method that you can use to retrieve the list. To build on the example from the docs:

```
>>> from django.http import QueryDict
>>> q = QueryDict('a=1&a=2&c=3')
>>> q
<QueryDict: {'a': ['1', '2'], 'c': ['3']}>
>>> q['a']  # gets the last item
u'2'
>>> q.getlist('a')  # gets the list
[u'1', u'2']
>>> q['c']  # gets the last (and only) item
u'3'
>>> q.getlist('c')  # gets the list (which contains a single item)
[u'3']
```

Comment: please, rollback my comments if you don't agree. Regards.

Comment: Wow, you're right. The form will instantiate with a QueryDict object, but not with a ordinary dictionary with lists (only a dictionary with single values). I just learned something! Thanks!